# CloudFormation issue: couldn't delete stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I create CloudFormation template for our resources, it includes Lambda functions, API Gateways, Roles, etc. For verifying our template I create CloudFormation stack using it, check some resources which I updated and after that I delete stack. But last time I got such message when I tried to delete stack:

> CloudFormation is waiting for NetworkInterfaces associated with the
>   Lambda Function to be cleaned up.

I tried to stop deletion process and restart it, but I faced the same issue again. What is the problem and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known issue. There are couple of things you can do.

1) Wait for the deletion to fail. Then try to delete. It should show you a checkbox to skip NetworkInterface. Select that.

2) Go to `EC2-->NetworkInterfaces` and detach/delete the NIC that was used by your resources. Then delete your CFT stack.

Comment: I'm wondering if this issue could be circumvented by adding to the stack a custom resource that did nothing on stack-create but detached/deleted the ENI in question on stack-delete.  I'm not totally sure though, how to determine which ENI it is that needs to be deleted.   `aws lambda get-function-configuration`, for example, does not explicitly say which ENI a lambda function is using.

Comment: That works. If you filter attachments by `description` == `AWS Lambda VPC ENI-<functionName>-*` you get the right ones, afaict.