# CloudFormation is waiting for NetworkInterfaces associated with the Lambda Function to be cleaned up

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation stack with Lambda function inside a VPC,
When trying to delete the stack, the AWS CloudFormation gets stuck for 25-30 at least,
I get the following message in the events -

```
CloudFormation is waiting for NetworkInterfaces associated with the Lambda Function to be cleaned up.
```

It seems to be due to ENIs being attached to the Functions and the SecurityGroups.

From the Console it did not allow me to delete either the ENI forcibly nor the Security Group, to which the ENI is attached,
So do I just have to wait?

I found some questions and blogs which are even 2 years old,
No solution from AWS?
Automations are supposed to be quick, this is proving to be a huge blocker.

**Reference -**
[CloudFormation issue: couldn't delete stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838963/cloudformation-issue-couldnt-delete-stack)
https://forum.serverless.com/t/very-long-delay-when-doing-sls-remove-of-lambda-in-a-vpc/2535

Comment: There's an open issue about it: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5008

Comment: This is a well-known issue with Lambdas in VPCs. Since you don't seem to be aware of this, they have come up with a solution to this issue, you'll just have to wait for it to be rolled out to your region: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/

Comment: This issue still occurs with the new Hyperplane ENIs.

Comment: If possible, referencing an existing security group for the lambda cuts down on this time significantly (though obviously that doesn't solve the underlying problem)

Comment: Up until a couple of months ago you could interview manually via the console to Detach and then Delete (to avoid the cloudformation long wait for delete) but that 'hack' is now closed off for ENI owned by a stack.

Answer (score 2):

As you and others have already mentioned, this is a known issue/"feature". When I last spoke about this with someone from AWS, there were no plans of changing this behavior. If time is really of the essence for you, one work-around you can try is this:

1. Update the Lambda resources in CloudFormation with `DeletionPolicy` set to `Retain`.
2. Manually (or via script/API) delete the Lambda and associated resources like ENIs

However, I would not recommend against the above mentioned work-around. It is easy to forget something which will leave you with a cluttered environment.

Answer (score 0):

I  still am facing the same problem. Strangely even after AWS folks mentioned that they have fixed it (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/)

Workaround options to mitigate the problem :

- Get the list of Lambda functions(with VPC connectivity) that are in waiting state. Delete them manually or with automation.
- Add Lambda function IAM(policy) with "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface" and "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface".
- Change DeletionPolicy on CF for Lambda functions with VPC as "Retain"

Comment: Can you add more details about option #2? What would that achieve?

Comment: @gshpychka in the .yml file

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver not sure I understand the answer. I was asking what adding the permissions would achieve